# Vuefire get a value from a data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I've got this on my Firebase DB :

[image]

I want to get the value of id, I tried many things but I cannot get it :(( There is something that I don't understand with this DB I think haha x)

In my program I want to get the value of id to put the id in a product and then increment id.

I do this (in methods postProduct) :

```
<template>
    <form>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
                <div class="card-image__picture">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-upgraded is-dirty">
                    <input id="linkIMG" v-model="product.linkIMG" type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input"/>
                    <label for="linkIMG" class="mdl-textfield__label">Picture URL</label>
                    <input id="name" v-model="product.name" type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input"/>
                    <label for="name" class="mdl-textfield__label">Product Name</label>
                    <input id="brand" v-model="product.brand" type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input"/>
                    <label for="brand" class="mdl-textfield__label">Product Name</label>
                    <input id="description" v-model="product.description" type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input"/>
                    <label for="description" class="mdl-textfield__label">Product Description</label>
                    <input id="price" v-model="product.price" type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"/>
                    <label for="price" class="mdl-textfield__label">Price of the Product</label>
                    <input id="category" v-model="product.category" type="number" class="mdl-textfield__input"/>
                    <label for="category" class="mdl-textfield__label">Categ of product</label>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <a @click.prevent="postProduct" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
                        POST A PRODUCT
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import FireBase from '../service/firebase'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                product: {
                    linkIMG: "",
                    category: 0,
                    brand: "",
                    name: "",
                    description: "",
                    price: 0,
                    id: 0
                }
            }
        },
        firebase: {
            ref: FireBase.database.ref('id')
        },
        methods: {
            postProduct: function() {
                var todoId = FireBase.database.ref('id') ;
                // Set l'id of product to id
                this.product.id = todoId;
                console.log(todoId);
                // Up id + 1
                todoId.set(todoId + 1);
                this.$root.$firebaseRefs.product.push(this.product)
                    .then(this.$router.push('/'));
                this.$router.push({name: 'Catalog'});
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you really much :))

Comment: Where you trigger this method `postProduct` ?

Comment: in inputs from the same file :)